# how to await the return of the auxiliar async method?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have this methods:

```
private async void myMethod01()
{
    await myAynchMethod();

    //more code
}


private void myMethod02()
{
    //code
    myMethod01();
    //more code
}
```

When I execute the code, when myMethod02 calls myMethod01, continue with the execution of //more code without wating that myMethod01 finish its code.

This is because the await in the myMethod01 returns the execution point to myMethod02 and myMethod02 continue with the next line of code after the call to mymethod01.

I would like to know if there is any way to wait in myMethod02 until myMethod02 finish its execution.

I would like that myMethod01 does not return a task if it's possible.

Thank so much.

Comment: You can always use `.Wait()` but why don't you want `myMethod01` to return a task? Relevant: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: `async void` is specifically to allow async event handlers.

Comment: For some reason if I use .wait(), the application hungs. the same if I use .Result to get the result.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía If you read the blog post that I linked to, you would likely understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is any way to wait in myMethod02 until
>   myMethod01 finish its execution.

And

> I would like that myMethod01 does not return a task if it's possible.

Are two conflicting sentences. If you'd like to **a**synchorounsly **wait** until `Method01` completes, and its asynchronous, you'd have to make it return a type with is *awaitable*. This doesn't have to be a `Task` necessarily, it can be a custom type which implements a `GetAwaiter` method an returns an awaiter which implements `INotifyCompletion` or `ICriticalNotifyCompletion`.

You can absolutely not have a method return `void` and asynchronously wait for it to complete, that doesn't make sense. You could instead simply run your code synchronously.

Comment: A final solution I return a task on mymethod01, and in this way I can await in the myMethod02.